# Unable to access classpath file in application.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

Am developing application in springboot using Msaccess database. My database file placed inside `src/main/resources`. I have configured database details in `application.properties` file. When I tried to load database file in `application.properties` its not working. Below is what I have tried in `application.properties` file.

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://classpath:database.accdb`

When I run the application, it return error message:

> UCAExc:::4.0.4 given file does not exist: classpath:database.accdb

Comment: in which folder it is placed?

Comment: both **database.accdb** and **application.properties** placed in **src/main/resources**

Comment: try to pass the absolute path of the file and verify whether it works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver cannot understand that `classpath:` is a special prefix. It expects a filename (real file path in a filesystem) and `classpath:database.accdb` is not a real one. Consider constructing the URL dynamically in Java code using [`ResourceUtils.getFile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html#getFile-java.lang.String-) (this method will return real file name for a classpath resource). Note that it will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the resource cannot be resolved to a file in the file system as it may be the case (e.g. when the resource is inside a JAR file).

Comment: So, Is there any way to assign file in application.properties which is in classpath.?

Answer (score 1):

Below post is going to help you

[Accessing a Microsoft Access database that is saved in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947833/accessing-a-microsoft-access-database-that-is-saved-in-the-classpath)

As i commented earlier, it should be an absolute path or path to the source directoy.